# XSL output everythin including node name, attributes, text

Tags: xml, xslt

On XSLT, Is there a simple way to output everything of a variable?

My variable is something like:

```
<node a="a">
  a
  <node>
    b
  </node>
</node>
```

So i want to output it as it is including tag names, attributes, text etc.

Thanks!

**AND:**

is it possible not to output some tags? such as

```
<a>aa
<b>bb
<c>cc</c></b></a>
```

i want to avoid b tag from output but want to output c? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? You mean "include in the result document"?

Comment: yes, sorry i am not used to functional programming may use wrong words :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$variable"/>
```

Comment: is it possible not to output some tags? such as <a>aa<b>bb<c>cc</c></b></a>. i want to avoid b tag form output but want to output c? thanks!

Comment: @user446141: See in my answer solutions to both of your questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Good question, +1.

**This transformation provides the answers to both your questions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vVarNode" select="/*/node"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vVarA" select="/*/a"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$vVarNode"/>
  ===========

  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vVarA"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (from which the two variables are "loaded"):

```
<doc>
 <node a="a">
    a
    <node>
     b
    </node>
 </node>

 <a>aa
  <b>bb
    <c>cc</c>
  </b>
 </a>
</doc>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced** (The content of the first variable is output "as-is", while `b` and its text-node children are "deleted" from what is output out of the content of the second variable):

```
<node a="a">
    a
    <node>
     b
    </node>
</node>
  ===========

  <a>aa
  <c>cc</c>
</a>
```